# JMeter - Auth file is not opening

Tags: testing, authorization, jmeter, stress-testing

I am working on JMeter Authorization Manager. I created a Test Plan by adding a Thread Group in it. I have an HTTP Authorization Manager in my Thread Group. I ran my test and it was successful. After that I click Save button of HTTP Authorization Manager. A text file is saved in bin folder named as `auth.txt` and having this data:

```
# JMeter generated Authorization file
10.10.10.42 username    password
```

After then I closed the JMeter. Later I wanted to open that .txt file again so that I should not have to enter username and password again, I added an HTTP Authorization Manager and  right-clicked on it. Clicked on Open and selected my file `auth.txt`. But it showed me the error:

> : only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not #
>   (position: START_DOCUMENT seen#...@1:1)

What wrong am I doing, can anybody specify please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was just doing wrong way to add Auth file.

It can be added through Load button in HTTP Authorization Manager like this:

[image]